# Kubernetes's Ingress has no effect on nginx-ingress-controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have deployed nginx :

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
```

And I exposed nginx

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --port 80 --type NodePort
```

And when execute this command

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE

nginx        NodePort    10.254.237.40   <none>        80:31111/TCP   22s

jenkins      ClusterIP   10.254.118.81   <none>        8080/TCP       45m
```

And I deployed Ingress file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /jenkins
          backend:
            serviceName: jenkins
            servicePort: 8080
```

And to know Output of ingress

```
-> kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
ingress.extensions "nginx" configured
-> kubectl get ing
NAME      HOSTS           ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
nginx     example.com             80        40m
```

And when Browser

```
http://Node-IP:31111
Returns Nginx's Welcome Page
```

And When Browser

```
http://http://Node-IP:31111/jenkins
Returns 404 Not Found
```

Is there something I do not understand?

And How to Solve this Issue?

thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you deployed in a way that doesnt include the functionality required to watch Ingress resources in kubernetes.

I recommend that you deploy nginx-ingress in an officially suggested manner: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#generic-deployment

I personally recommend the helm chart option: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm

> NGINX Ingress controller can be installed via Helm using the chart
>   stable/nginx-ingress from the official charts repository. To install
>   the chart with the release name my-nginx:
>
> helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name my-nginx If the kubernetes
>   cluster has RBAC enabled, then run:
>
> helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name my-nginx --set
>   rbac.create=true Detect installed version:
>
> POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx -o
>   jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME --
>   /nginx-ingress-controller --version

In addition, see the above answer by @Rico regarding passing the correct host headers:

> 1. Try running:
>
>    ```
>    curl -H 'Host: example.com' http://Node-IP:31111/jenkins
>    ```
> 2. Modify the `/etc/hosts` to have an entry `Node-IP example.com`file on your machine and just browse to:
>
>    ```
>    http://example.com:31111/jenkins
>    ```

Comment: I tried to use helm , but there is failure , can you see this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535811/can-not-install-nginx-by-using-helm-over-kubernetes

Comment: @AhmedMItman Hi I checked your question and I see you figured it out :). This is great! If my answer helped, you please mark it as accepted, so others know how to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to use the `Node-IP` if you want to get to the jenkins endpoint. In this case, you need to use `example.com`. But you need the Layer 7 Host header so that the ingress understands it. To test it, you need to modify it. A couple of ways you can do it:

1. Try running:

   ```
   curl -H 'Host: example.com' http://Node-IP:31111/jenkins
   ```
2. Modify the `/etc/hosts` to have an entry `Node-IP example.com`file on your machine and just browse to:

   ```
   http://example.com:31111/jenkins
   ```

Note that you are using a `NodePort` for you service. You can use a `LoadBalancer` type to avoid specifying the port. (Use the default port 80). You can also use the clusterIP `10.254.237.40`, but to access it you would have to be in one the machines in your Kubernetes cluster.