# Can not install nginx by using helm over kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-helm

I have kubernetes Cluster v1.10 over centos 7 , bare-metal

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0-rc.3", GitCommit:"28d295be2a94115b786ee277dffcc2b5483bde47", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.11.0-rc.3", GitCommit:"28d295be2a94115b786ee277dffcc2b5483bde47", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

I am trying to install nginx using helm

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name nginx
```

It returns

```
Error: release nginx failed: 
clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-nginx-ingress" is 
forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: 
[PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["configmaps"], Verbs: 
["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["configmaps"], 
Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources: 
["endpoints"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], 
Resources:["endpoints"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
[""], Resources:["nodes"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
[""], Resources:["nodes"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
[""], Resources:["pods"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
[""], Resources:["pods"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
[""], Resources:["secrets"], Verbs:["watch"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["nodes"], Verbs:["get"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["get"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs:["list"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], Verbs: 
["update"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["services"], 
Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"], Resources: 
["ingresses"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"], 
Resources:["ingresses"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{APIGroups: 
["extensions"], Resources:["ingresses"], Verbs:["watch"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["events"], Verbs:["create"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:[""], Resources:["events"], Verbs:["patch"]} 
PolicyRule{APIGroups:["extensions"], Resources: 
["ingresses/status"], Verbs:["update"]}] user=& 
{system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default 8f248058-b684-11e8- 
b781-daf0a0c10949 [system:serviceaccounts 
system:serviceaccounts:kube-system system:authenticated] map[]} 
ownerrules=[] ruleResolutionErrors=[]
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Thank You :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Search I think this is the solution

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name ingress --namespace kube-system --set rbac.create=false --set rbac.createRole=false --set rbac.createClusterRole=false
```

OR

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

As `kubectl apply -f` is used to create or update resources, Helm, on the other hand, can be called Kubernetes Package Manager. The solution you have posted is a workaround as the question is about Helm and not how to create resources using the `kubectl apply`. Adding `--set rbac.create=false` indicates that you probably deployed Tiller with no RBAC support. The question is, was it done intentionally? If you don't have RBAC authorization turned on, you can keep using `--set rbac.create=false`; if you want RBAC on, you have to add Tiller service account the `cluster-admin` role.

You can find how to configure it properly [here.](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md)

More information about installation and configuration of Helm and Tiller is available [here](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/) and the detailed explanation of the similar case in this Github [issue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/256).